How to add buttons/tabs to the excel backstage open screen?
I'm trying to add a button to the opening screen of Excel. I'm able to hide some buttons but adding one seems tricky and there is no documentation about it.
as you can see in the image I'm Able to hide the Open Button using the code
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="OnLoad">
  <backstage onShow="OnShow" onHide="OnHide" >
    <tab idMso="TabRecent"   visible="false"     >
    </tab>
  </backstage>
</customUI>

but adding any button is only showing on the backstage after opening a file and not on the first screen
